# Detect hover in Microsoft Word Add-In

Tags: ms-word, office-js, word-addins

I'm trying to develop an [Add-In](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins?view=office-js) for Microsoft Word. The basic idea being to load some key words into the document and then when the user hovers over one of the key words a box pops up to show more information, like on Wikipedia or Facebook.

Looking over the [api reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word?view=office-js) I see that the popup box isn't possible, and that's okay I could just make it appear in the Add-In's panel.

I read about [bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.bindings?view=office-js), but it seems they can't detect a hover or even a click event?  I thought about hacking something together with links but I don't think that would be very UI friendly.

The only thing I can think of to make it kind of possible is to have the user manually highlight the key word (sometimes the key word is more than one word), then have them click a "search" button in the Add-In's panel that would read the selected range and compare it against a database of words. It just seems very anti user compared to the original idea.

Does anyone know of a better way to achieve this?

Comment: About the only thing you could use would be the Change event for the Selection, which is part of the original APIs. That could provide context-sensitive content in the task pane...

Comment: Thanks Cindy, that's what I came up with as well.